# How Using View Stub increase performance then adding view in container at Runtime

Tags: android, performance, view, viewstub

I know i can create a view stub

```
<ViewStub android:id="@+id/stub"
           android:inflatedId="@+id/subTree"
           android:layout="@layout/mySubTree"
           android:layout_width="120dip"
           android:layout_height="40dip" />
```

and inflate it by 
ViewStub stub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.stub);
View inflated = stub.inflate();

but how it different in performance then using a Linear Layout and adding a child views at runtime

Comment: it is, more or less, the same